# Best approach tor finding last customer transaction?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column in my pandas dataframe that identifies the last time a customer bought something. I was originally thinking about using groupby and min statement, but the problem with this approach is that if a customer purchases again it will always just show the first transaction.

`df['earlier_sale'] = df.groupby('Customer_Id')['Sale_Date'].transform('min')`

I was thinking of creating a nested for loop that evaluates each row, but i'm not able to figure it out or find any examples online that i can use as a guide.

```
for value in df["Customer_Id"]: 
    for second_value in df["Customer_Id"]:
    
df["Earlier_transaction"] = Earlier_Transaction
```

Input:

| Sale_Date | Customer_Id | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2008-01-01 | 001 | 10 |
| 2008-01-02 | 002 | 10 |
| 2008-01-02 | 001 | 12 |
| 2008-01-03 | 001 | 14 |
| 2008-01-03 | 003 | 50 |

Desired Output:

Input file:

| Sale_Date | Customer_Id | Amount | Earlier Transaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2008-01-01 | 001 | 10 | - |
| 2008-01-02 | 002 | 10 | - |
| 2008-01-02 | 001 | 12 | 2008-01-01 |
| 2008-01-03 | 001 | 14 | 2008-01-02 |
| 2008-01-03 | 003 | 50 | - |

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated. I've tried to look for a variety of different approaches but I am not having much luck.

Comment: What is the `dtype` of column `Sale_Date`? Is the column `Sale_Date` already sorted?

Comment: I was using pandas datetime for that column, and yes it would be sorted already.

Comment: Try shift `df['Earlier Transaction'] = df.groupby('Customer_Id')['Sale_Date'].shift()`

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into what shift does. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there: use `groupby`, and find the `max` date within each group.  If you have troubles with the date format being recognized, then convert your dates to `datetime`, which is a properly ordered data type.

Comment: Thank you! If i use groupby and max, won't it only find one related transaction per customer though? Sorry if i'm just not understanding.

Comment: You asked for the last time; that's what `max("Sale_Date")` will give you.

Comment: @Prune Your thinking is almost correct but `max` will always give the max value per group and i guess OP want the value of last transaction date..by the way I'm not the one who downvoted https://imgur.com/a/F6WBKum

Comment: Understood -- but int hat case, OP needs to change the question to specify the actual desired output.

Comment: @Prune Yes. Agreed!

Comment: Thanks both - the original question could have been clearer. I tried to update the desired output to give a better sense of what i'm looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: @Prune Maybe you can update your answer using the `shift` method instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df
   Sale_Date Customer_Id  Amount
0 2021-02-15         001      13
1 2021-02-15         002      13
2 2021-02-16         001      11
3 2021-02-16         002      17
4 2021-02-17         001      14
5 2021-02-17         002      18
6 2021-02-18         001      10
7 2021-02-18         002      16
8 2021-02-19         001      11

>>> df["Earlier Transaction"] = df.groupby("Customer_Id")["Sale_Date"].shift(1)
>>> df
   Sale_Date Customer_Id  Amount Earlier Transaction
0 2021-02-15         001      13                 NaT
1 2021-02-15         002      13                 NaT
2 2021-02-16         001      11          2021-02-15
3 2021-02-16         002      17          2021-02-15
4 2021-02-17         001      14          2021-02-16
5 2021-02-17         002      18          2021-02-16
6 2021-02-18         001      10          2021-02-17
7 2021-02-18         002      16          2021-02-17
8 2021-02-19         001      11          2021-02-18
```